# How to delete table rows from a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-delete

I'm having trouble trying to delete rows.

All rows are selected and displayed on a `ListBox` control.
Then, when calling the `btnObrisi_Click` event (Obrisi = delete), the selected item from the `ListBox` will be deleted.

The item is actually removed from the control, but the value is not deleted from the database.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private string conString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
private SqlConnection con;
private SqlCommand com;
private DataTable dt;
private SqlDataAdapter da;

private DataTable SelectAll()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    com = new SqlCommand();
    dt = new DataTable();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM predmeti";
    da.SelectCommand = com;
    da.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}

private void Obrisi(int id)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText = "DELETE FROM predmeti WHERE predmetID = @predmetID";
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@predmetID", id);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Obrisano");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
         con.Close();
    }
}

private void Citaj()
{
    listBox1.ValueMember = "predmetID";
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "ime_predmeta";
    listBox1.DataSource = SelectAll();
}

private void btnOsvezi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Citaj();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Citaj();
}

private void btnObrisi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedValue);
    Obrisi(id);
    Citaj();
}
```

Comment: How do you check the failed delete?

Comment: @Steve 
I open database, and there is nothing deleted.

Comment: Do you open the database in the bin\debug folder or the database in your main project folder?

Comment: @Steve Both wayes, same thing. Code is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a database file in your project and then you build the project, the database file could be copied from the root project folder into the output (bin\debug or bin\release) folder.
This behavior is controlled by the `Copy To Output Directory` property on the database file.

If you have this property set to Copy Always then, every time you build your project a fresh copy of the database file is copied from the root project folder to the output directory overwriting the one already there and destroying the changes you have made in the previous debug session.

A suggested fix is to change this property to `Copy Never` or `Copy if Newer`

See a detailed explanation on [MSDN at this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)

The shortcut `|DataDirectory|` in the connection string points (for a winforms project) to the bin\debug or bin\release relative subfolder of the current project, Any changes made by your program works on the database located there, but these changes are overwritten at the next run

Comment: Problem Solved, thank you very, very much. 

I was set Solution Explorer to show all, and then i jus go in bin and select database, where is all normal. Thank you one more time, i will check up your answer.